# Why does my Unit Test keep saying NullPointerException? I'm using @BeforeClass and it doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, unit-testing, model-view-controller, service, junit4

```
public class FlooringMasteryServiceLayerImplTest {

    private FlooringMasteryServiceLayer service;

    /*public FlooringMasteryServiceLayerImplTest() {
        ApplicationContext ctx
                = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        service
                = ctx.getBean("serviceLayer", FlooringMasteryServiceLayer.class);
    }*/

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    
    @Test
    public void testCreatedOrderFileNameFromDate() {
        
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2020-11-25");
        
        String orderFileName = service.createOrderFileNameFromDate(date);
        
        assertEquals(orderFileName, "Orders_11252020.txt", "The order file name generated was incorrect.");
    }

}
```

I can't seem to find what the solution is for this Failed Unit Test. I have @BeforeClass so I believe it is running JUnit4. It just keeps saying NullPointerException and I don't know how to solve this issue. Please help

Comment: What are you expecting `@BeforeClass` to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I just want my unit test to work and also understand why it wasn't working in the first place and why it is displaying a NullPointerException.

Comment: service is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your variable "service" inside @BeforeClass method.